# What is the blob_name for Azure generate_blob_sas() Python SDK, when folder paths are involved?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, blob, azure-python-sdk

I'd like to [`generate_blob_sas`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob?view=azure-python#azure-storage-blob-generate-blob-sas) using the Azure Python SDK.

The blob URL looks something like this:
`https://<account_name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container_name>/<folder_1>/<folder_2>/<blob_name>.jpg`

The snippet in question looks something like this:

```
# Generate SAS token
blob_sas_token = generate_blob_sas(
    account_name = storage_account_name,
    container_name = storage_container_name,
    blob_name = "",
    account_key = storage_account_key,
    permission = BlobSasPermissions.from_string(TOKEN_PERMISSIONS),
    expiry = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(minutes=TOKEN_DURATION_MINUTES)
)
```

**Question**:

- Does the `blob_name` consist of `<folder_1>/<folder_2>/<blob_name>.jpg`? OR
- Does the `blob_name` consist only of `<blob_name>.jpg`?

Comment: It is `<folder_1>/<folder_2>/<blob_name>.jpg`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - Does the  `blob_name`  consist of  `<folder_1>/<folder_2>/<blob_name>.jpg`? OR  Does the  `blob_name`  consist only of  `<blob_name>.jpg`?

I agree with @Gauravmantri, you need to use the blob name with path **`<folder_1>/<folder_2>/<blob_name>.jpg.`**

Here is workaround for the generate sas token with blob name using python:

**Code:**

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from azure.storage.blob import generate_blob_sas, BlobSasPermissions

# Set the storage account details
storage_account_name = "venkat123"
storage_account_key = "accountkey"
storage_container_name = "test"
blob_name = "folder1/subfolder1/image1.png"

# Set the SAS token parameters
sas_expiry = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1)
sas_permissions = BlobSasPermissions(read=True, write=True)

# Generate SAS token for the blob
blob_sas_token = generate_blob_sas(
    account_name=storage_account_name,
    container_name=storage_container_name,
    blob_name=blob_name,
    account_key=storage_account_key,
    permission=sas_permissions,
    expiry=sas_expiry
)

# Construct the full URL with the SAS token
blob_url_with_sas = f"https://{storage_account_name}.blob.core.windows.net/{storage_container_name}/{blob_name}?{blob_sas_token}"

print("Blob URL with SAS token:")
print(blob_url_with_sas)
```

**Output:**

```
Blob URL with SAS token:
https://<storage account name>.blob.core.windows.net/test/folder1/subfolder1/image1.png?<SAS token>
```

[image]

**Browser:**
[image]